# How to solve this polynomial?

Tags: polynomials

How to get the solution for this polynomial?
If $x/y + y/x = -1$ where $x$ and $y$ are not equal to zero, then what would be the value of $x^3 -y^3$

Comment: Note that there are no **real** $x,y$ such that $\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}=-1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:
$x^3 - y^3 = (x - y)(x^2 + y^2 + xy)$.  Factor out $xy$ from the second term.

Answer (score 1):

Fint :we have $1+z+z^2+\dots+z^n=\frac{z^{n+1}-1}{z-1}$ and assume  $z=\frac{x}{y}$ then $z+\frac1z=-1\to z^2+z+1=0\to \frac{z^3-1}{z-1}=0$

Comment: $\Large\color{blue}{+1}{nice work}$$\Large\color{blue}{❀}$ @Maisam Hedyelloo

Comment: @faranak50:thx faranak

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{x}{y} + \frac y x = -1\\x^2+y^2=-xy\tag{multiply both sides by xy}\\x+y+xy=0$ Take the hint above to complete your working.